# onmouseout and onmouseover

Tags: javascript

I am working on homework that involves working with javascript. Part of my homework assignment is to use the event handlers onmouseout and onmouseouver. What is supposed to happen when the user hovers over a specific div element, the font size grows by 25%, and when the user mouses out of the div element, the font size goes back to normal. My question is, is it possible to incorporate both an onmouseover function and an onmouseout function into one function? Somehow that is what my teacher wants us to do. I have this started so far.

```
function FontSize(x)
{
    x.style.fonstSize = large;
}
```

I'm also thinking this isnt the correct code to make the font 25% larger, but I'm not sure how to really incorporate an onmouseout in this function.

Answer (score 3):

As a teacher myself, I am 99% sure that by "one function" the instructor means one general-purpose function to change the font size, not one function which uses conditional statements to work backwards and figure out whether it should be doing onmouseout or onmouseover.

Your script should contain:

```
function resize(elem, percent) { elem.style.fontSize = percent; }
```

Your HTML should contain:

```
<div onmouseover="resize(this, '125%')" onmouseout="resize(this, '100%')"
Text within div..
</div>
```

Note: Situations such as here, are exactly why JavaScript has the keyword "this"--to save us from needing to use complicated document.getElementById() statements.

Comment: +1 Indeed you are a teacher.. I went couple of steps ahead without thinking at a teachers viewpoint and answering. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use "%" property for controlling font-size as described [here](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) with the following code.

```
 document.getElementById("div1").onmouseover = function() {        
            document.getElementById("div1").style.fontSize  = "125%"
                        };

 document.getElementById("div1").onmouseout = function() {        
            document.getElementById("div1").style.fontSize  = "100%";
                        };
```

Here is the working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LxhdU/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Call the same function on both events, and pass a parameter to indicate whether the fontsize should increase or decrease.

```
ChangeFontSize = function(element, shouldIncreaseFontsize)
{
    var small=14;
    var large = small * 1.25;

    if(shouldIncreaseFontsize) {
         element.style.fontSize = large + "px";
    }
    else {
         element.style.fontSize = small + "px";
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TMHbW/1/

Comment: where you are declaring large and small as variables and assigning them those values, if i wanted to do percent, would I just put a % at the end. for example, `var large = 25%`. would that work and increase by 25%?

Comment: Well, if you've defined small, you can do `var large = 1.25 * small;` That's simple arithmetic.

Comment: ok. would it be possible to pass in only one parameter and still have the same affect? when i call this function, i am calling it this way. `onmouseover = "FontSize(this)"`

Comment: I've updated my answer with working jsfiddle code. Check it out!

Comment: Throw in another parameter like this:
`onmouseover = "FontSize(this, true);"` and `onmouseout="FontSize(this, false);"`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you do not need to call both the events on the element explicitly instead  extension you create will do that.Extend the `Element`'s prototype. Jquery also does similar to this.

[Ref Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

See Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/4fs7V/

```
Element.prototype.hover= function( fnOver, fnOut ) {

    this.onmouseover=fnOver;
    this.onmouseout=fnOut || fnOver;
        return this;
    };


document.getElementById('test').hover(function(){
                                         //do your mouseover stuff
                                                },
                                     function(){
                                           //do your mouseout stuff
                                     });
```

### Update

Same can be achieved with just one function too:-

Hover me

```
.largeFont {
    font-size:125%;
}

Element.prototype.hover = function (fnOver, fnOut) {
    this.onmouseover = fnOver;
    this.onmouseout = fnOut || fnOver;
    return this;
};

document.getElementById('test').hover(changeMe);

function changeMe()
{
    if(this.hasAttribute('class'))
    {
        this.removeAttribute('class');
    }
    else
    {
         this.setAttribute('class', 'largeFont');
    }
}
```

Comment: only thing is, have not covered JQuery in my class. Only javascript

Comment: This is not jquery. This is javascript. You can check the updated fiddle for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something simple like the following. The `large` and `small` values can be whatever you need them to be for the font size to work or they can be variables you've defined in prior code.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/EAbYn/

```
 function doHover(e) {
    if (e.type=='mouseover') {
          this.style.fontSize = "large";   
    } else {

          this.style.fontSize = "small";  
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById('myelement')
el.onmouseout =doHover;
el.onmouseover=doHover;
```